# Clicking on "View in Store" does nothing

Tags: windows-8, browser, windows-store, windows-store-app

I have some problems when I want to install any Windows Store app from [apps.microsoft.com](http://apps.microsoft.com). The button of the application from the store does nothing. I am using Chrome mainly.

I want to install the [AccuWeather App](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/accuweather-for-windows-8/cf317822-d092-42e8-8066-4cda958a8f7f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is described [here](http://www.zdnet.com/cant-shop-for-windows-store-apps-using-chrome-but-is-google-being-evil-7000004918/) in detail. Basically it boils down to how Microsoft has coded the site to detect Chrome, and also its usage of a custom URI protocol handler named **ms-windows-store**,  which happens to be registered by the Store app on Windows 8, and which Chrome apparently ignores.

As always, best to use IE for all things related to Microsoft.

Comment: It works fine on Firefox as well